# UIImageView over another

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage

I have two UIImageView's one that will contain my product image, and one that I had a graphic designer make that is this:

[image]

Is there anyway I could have that image overlay another UIImageView to give it those effects? My designer stated I could put any smart object in there where the green is, but I assume he was referring to Photoshop, as he doesn't develop and I've only heard that term really used in Photoshop. Can this be achieved with XCode?

[image]

Comment: It's not clear what your desired effect is.  Do you want one image on top of that one, with transparency so both show? Or something else? A mockup using Photoshop would help.

Comment: Exactly, the one on top to be placed over my main UIImage to give it that glossy look and white border. The one below is just a green circle. I will replace it with an actual image and edit my post so it can be seen better

Comment: There sorry about that, added another with an actual image, and it's basically just one file in Photoshop right now that I drag in image into, save and I'm good to go. I basically just want that top part to overlay my UIImageView

Comment: You don't even require 2 images. You just need the base image, the reflect effect can be achieved programmatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the top designer image has a transparency, place your UIImageView  behind this image, setting the width and height matching the diameter of the designed circle frame image.

Your UIImageView connected from your storyboard or xib to your class file

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *photoImage;
```

Then within your viewDidLoad add the following code which will mask the object so it is cropped to a circle image.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{

    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.photoImage.layer.cornerRadius = self.photoImage.frame.size.width/2;
    self.photoImage.layer.masksToBounds = YES;

}
```

I hope this helps